Unable to retrieve C# BitArray from SQL Server VARBINARY(MAX) column
Using SQL Server and SSMS, how do I read a BitArray created in C# from a SQL Server VARBINARY(MAX) column?
At this point I am not able to change how this value is stored; I am stuck with a design that serializes a c# BitArray and stores it in a Sql Server VARBINARY(MAX) column. I am easily able to read the true-false values by de-serializing the VARBINARY(MAX) value back into a c# BitArray, that works fine. I'm interested in knowing if there is a way to do this in a Sql Server script.
Several people have posted links to explanations of the Sql Server bitwise operators or to articles on database normalization. That does not answer this question. I'm not using bit flags; I also cannot change how this value is stored. The C# BitArray can contain several hundred to several thousand values (a BitArray is similar to a generic List<bool>, except it is optimized).
I can easily reconstitute and read this BitArray in c#. I'm interested in learning if there is a way to read directly from the VARBINARY(MAX) column inside a Sql Server stored procedure and determine if an item at index "x" is true or false. Thank you to anyone who knows if this is possible and can provide an example of how to do it.
Using C#, I'm creating a BitArray like this:
var bitArray = new BitArray(2);

I'm setting the bits like this:
bitArray[0] = true;
bitArray[1] = false;

...and so on.
I'm sending the bitArray to a SQL Server stored procedure, where it is saved into a VARBINARY(MAX) column. The SqlParameter I create in C# looks like this:
var byteArray = new byte[2]; 
bitArray.CopyTo(byteArray,0);   
new SqlParameter("@BitArray", SqlDbType.VarBinary) { Size=-1, Value = byteArray }

In my stored procedure I'm saving @BitArray to a VARBINARY(MAX) column. After saving it, I can retrieve the value back out of the table in a C# application and read the individual true/false items from the reconstituted bit array. This all works just fine.
I open a SqlDataReader using
SELECT MyByteArray FROM MyTable WHERE Id = @MyId

I fetch the byte array in data reader and convert it to a bit array:
Byte[] myByteArray = (byte[])reader.GetValue(0);
BitArray myReconstitutedBitArray = new BitArray(myByteArray)

I can then read from myReconstitutedBitArray and see that everything works just fine:

myReconstitutedBitArray[0] = true.
myReconstitutedBitArray[1] = false.

and so on. Everything works fine.
The problem is, in SQL Server I need to be able to read from MyTable.MyByteArray and see the individual true/false values, but I cannot. Everything returns false. I am using SQL Server 2022, so I'm using the GET_BIT method, but it returns false for everything. No matter what I put in the index position, it returns false. I know the field has the correct values, because I can read them in C#.
How can I read these values in SQL Server?
Every call like this returns false, even though I know the bit is true and I can see the true value in C#:
SELECT GET_BIT(MyByteArray, 0) FROM MyTable WHERE MyId = @MyId
SELECT GET_BIT(MyByteArray, 1) FROM MyTable WHERE MyId = @MyId


How is your bitarray stored in sql server, i mean what's the binary value?

Don't you mean var boolArray = new bool[2]; bitArray.CopyTo(boolArray, 0);? It seems you're converting bits to bytes at the moment.

I don't understand either question. Everything works in c#. Everything is being stored correctly. I can pull the bit array out of the Sql Server VARBINARY(MAX) column into a c# BitArray and the values are correct. My question is, how can I pull these correct values out of the SqlServer field in SSMS and read them? That is all I want to do. I'm able to do it in c#; I want to do the exact same thing in SqlServer, and cannot figure out how to do it.

I'm just too lazy to write the C# app, What does: SELECT MyByteArray FROM MyTable WHERE MyId = @MyId displays after you performed your serialization?

Oh well, i did it. i think the problem is that the binary array is serialized in wrong order for the GET_BIT to do what you want it to do, so byte[2] {1, 0] becomes 0x0100, it works fine, because de-serialization uses same logic, but when you peek into raw bytes, it doesn't do what you want it to do, because GET_BIT reads from the right side. You should anyway use byte[1] but it won't help if you do need to store larger values

Why are you doing (or attempting to do) this? Are you familiar with database normalization?

The following may be of interest: Using Bitmasks for Efficient Data Filtering

Does this answer your question? Comparing two bitmasks in SQL to see if any of the bits match

@siggemannen I don't understand what you mean by "use byte[1]". Can you post a brief sql statement that demonstrates what you mean? Assume I'm trying to read item 2, in a sql server statement, from a c# BitArray with three elements serialized and stored in a Sql Server VARBINARY(MAX) as described above in a field named dbo.MyTable.MyByteArray.

If you familiarize yourself with database normalization as I previously mentioned, you may conclude, that a database may not be the correct solution in this case. Not all data is suitable for a database. Why do you believe that a database is appropriate here?

I agree though that proper database normalization would normally mean that this would be some kind of EAV design, unless space and performance was at an absolute premium.

You can see here https://dbfiddle.uk/6dKIVQpi what happens if you have a two byte binary value in SQL. GET_BIT begins on the right, whereas BitArray packs it from the left. So you need to do some arithmetic GET_BIT(YourValue, DATALENGTH(YourValue) * 8 - x - 1) where x is the zero-based bit number you want. Also to ensure your value is being copied in correctly you want var byteArray = new byte[bitArray.Length / 8];

Unfortunately the C# BitArray and SQL Server's GET_BIT just work a little different.
So something will need to be done to map between the 2 with minimal friction (C# is more flexible than SQL, so its 'easier' to solve the mismatch in C#)

A bit of awkward SQL code
A bit of awkward C# code (can create helper extension methods)
Serialize the BitArray yourself (can copy source code and modify / evil private variable access)
Write your own BitArray class

Recommendation
I would just add some helper extension methods to the BitArray
public static class BitArrayExtension
{
    public static bool GET_BIT(this BitArray bitArray, int offset)
        => bitArray.Get(bitArray.Length - 8 - (offset & 0xF8) + (offset & 0x7));

    public static void SET_BIT(this BitArray bitArray, int offset, bool value)
        => bitArray.Set(bitArray.Length - 8 - (offset & 0xF8) + (offset & 0x7), value);
}

var myBitArray = new BitArray(24);
myBitArray.SET_BIT(6, true);
myBitArray.GET_BIT(6); // == SELECT GET_BIT(MyBitArray, 6) FROM ...

(Edit) Alternatively you can create an SQL helper function that behaves like BitArray.Get
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.BitArrayGet(@value VARBINARY(MAX), @offset INT)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    -- fairly standard bit unpacking code
    RETURN CAST(SUBSTRING(@value, @offset>>3 + 1, 1) AS INT) & (0x1 << (@offset & 0x7))
END

-- change from this
SELECT GET_BIT(MyByteArray, 3) FROM MyTable WHERE MyId = @MyId
-- into this (and now works as expected)
SELECT dbo.BitArrayGet(MyByteArray, 3) FROM MyTable WHERE MyId = @MyId

Showing the difference between SQL Server in /**/ and BitArray in []
var flags = new BitArray(24)
{
    //       0x01 == 0b0000_0001 ~ GET_BIT(MyByteArray, 16)
    /* 16 */ [00] = true, // <--
    /* 17 */ [01] = !true,
    /* 18 */ [02] = !true,
    /* 19 */ [03] = !true,
    /* 20 */ [04] = !true,
    /* 21 */ [05] = !true,
    /* 22 */ [06] = !true,
    /* 23 */ [07] = !true,
    
    //       0x04 == 0b0000_0100 ~ GET_BIT(MyByteArray, 10)
    /* 08 */ [08] = !true,
    /* 09 */ [09] = !true,
    /* 10 */ [10] = true,  // <--
    /* 11 */ [11] = !true,
    /* 12 */ [12] = !true,
    /* 13 */ [13] = !true,
    /* 14 */ [14] = !true,
    /* 15 */ [15] = !true,

    //       0x40 == 0b0100_0000 ~ GET_BIT(MyByteArray, 6)
    /* 00 */ [16] = !true,
    /* 01 */ [17] = !true,
    /* 02 */ [18] = !true,
    /* 03 */ [19] = !true,
    /* 04 */ [20] = !true,
    /* 05 */ [21] = !true,
    /* 06 */ [22] = true, // <--
    /* 07 */ [23] = !true
};
var byteArray = new byte[flags.Length / 8];
flags.CopyTo(byteArray, 0); // will write out => 0x010440 (this is what you will see in SQL Server)

How to Map
Notice the symmetry between the mappings (e.g. /* 06 */ [22] and /* 22 */ [06]) hence we only need one function for
both way conversions
int SqlServerOffset(int bitArrayOffset) => (myBitArray.Length / 8 - bitArrayOffset / 8 - 1) * 8 + bitArrayOffset % 8
int BitArrayOffset(int sqlServerOffset) => (myBitArray.Length / 8 - sqlServerOffset / 8 - 1) * 8 + sqlServerOffset % 8
// same as above but using bit operations
int SqlServerOffset(int bitArrayOffset) => myBitArray.Length - 8 - (bitArrayOffset & 0xF8) + (bitArrayOffset & 0x7)


(LEN(MyBitArray) - @BitArrayOffset/8 - 1) * 8 + (@BitArrayOffset % 8) SqlServerOffset
LEN(MyBitArray)<<3 - 8 - (@BitArrayOffset & 0xF8) + (@BitArrayOffset & 0x7) SqlServerOffset

Edit
In reply to OP's answer. The GENERATE_SERIES can be used on SQL Server 2022 to remove the need for the while loop
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.GetBitArrayValues2022(@varbinaryValue VARBINARY(MAX))
RETURNS @bitValues TABLE (
    BitPosition INT,
    BitValue BIT
)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @bitLength int = LEN(@varbinaryValue)<<3

    INSERT INTO
        @bitValues
    SELECT
        [value],
        -- fairly standard bit unpacking code
        CAST(SUBSTRING(@varbinaryValue, [value]>>3 + 1, 1) AS INT) & (0x1 << ([value] & 0x7))
        -- same outcome as above but using GET_BIT
        -- (no real advantage to this approach given the complex offset calculation)
        -- GET_BIT(@varbinaryValue, @bitLength - 8 - ([value] & 0xF8) + ([value] & 0x7))
    FROM
        GENERATE_SERIES(0, @bitLength - 1, 1)

    RETURN
END


Wow, that took a lot longer than I thought it would. Thank you for the guidance @Kwiksilver. The function below works:
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.GetBitArrayValues(@varbinaryValue VARBINARY(MAX))
RETURNS @bitValues TABLE (
    BitPosition INT,
    BitValue BIT
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @bitArray VARBINARY(MAX) = @varbinaryValue;
    DECLARE @bitArrayLength INT = DATALENGTH(@bitArray) * 8;
    DECLARE @bitPosition INT = 0;

    WHILE @bitPosition < @bitArrayLength
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @byteIndex INT = @bitPosition / 8;
        DECLARE @bitIndex INT = @bitPosition % 8;
        DECLARE @byteValue INT = CAST(SUBSTRING(@bitArray, @byteIndex + 1, 1) AS INT);
        DECLARE @bitMask INT = POWER(2, @bitIndex);
        DECLARE @bitValue BIT;

        IF (@byteValue & @bitMask) > 0
            SET @bitValue = 1;
        ELSE
            SET @bitValue = 0;

        INSERT INTO @bitValues (BitPosition, BitValue)
        VALUES (@bitPosition, @bitValue);

        SET @bitPosition = @bitPosition + 1;
    END

    RETURN;
END

And to call it, pass the serialized BitArray (which I store in a SqlServer VARBINARY(MAX) column):
SELECT * FROM dbo.GetBitArrayValues(0x0000400801820085000000000000801800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)

